# RequestMapping and Controller annotations. Controller is not being hit

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, controller, spring-annotations

I've a controller with @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/copyRightVersion")
public class CopyrightAndVersionController extends BaseController {

    protected CopyrightAndVersionController() {
        super(CopyrightAndVersionController.class);
    }

    /**
     * Reads copyright and version from respective files.
     *
     * @return the model and view
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getVersion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getCopyrightAndVersion() {
        LOGGER.debug("in getCopyrightAndVersion method");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("copyrightAndVersion");

        mav.getModelMap().put("copyright", "test copyright");
        mav.getModelMap().put("version", "test version");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

In logs I see that

```
 DispatcherServlet with name 'xtreme' processing GET request for [/Xtreme/copyRightVersion/getVersion.do]
Looking up handler method for path /copyRightVersion/getVersion.do
Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.xtreme.controller.CopyrightAndVersionController.getCopyrightAndVersion()]
tableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'copyrightAndVersionController'
 Last-Modified value for [/Xtreme/copyRightVersion/getVersion.do] is: -1
 Successfully completed request
```

It never hits Controller's method getCopyrightAndVersion() though DispatcherServlet correctly identified handler for this. It doesn't print message in log. Even in remote debugging it is not hit.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you get as response?

Comment: im getting response code 302 (302 found) and redirected to home page.

Comment: Cannot it be some `HandlerInterceptor`?

Comment: thanks @axtavt. that helped. I didn't notice requestInterceptor defined in beans config file.